# How to get the value of the key in array_combine

Tags: php, codeigniter

Guys I need your help now. My question is that how can I get the value of the key in array_combine ? I want to get the value of the shipment fee based on the quant for example 
This is my structure please help me if its really wrong.

```
      $quant = 3;
      $x = $quant- 1;
      $z =$quant ;
      $shipment_fee = $this->Model_checkout->get_shipment($shop_item_sk);
      foreach($shipment_fee as $key)
      {
        $ship_fee = explode('^',$key->shop_item_ship_price); //ex. 1^3
        $ship_num = explode('^',$key->shop_item_ship_num); //ex. 100^250
      }
      $shipment = array_combine($ship_num,$ship_fee);
      $shipment_fees = '';
      for($y=$x;$y<$z;$y++)
      {
        $shipment_fees = $shipment[$y];
/*line 47 */ echo $shipment_fees; //The value must be 250
      }
```

The problem is that I got the value but there's an error on line 47. Undefined offset: 2 . Advance thanks guys.

Comment: I got the answer .. $shipment[$z] thanks anyway

Comment: if your *$ship_num* is 100 or 250, you cannot expect to find them with an *$y* value that is 2 or 3 (*$quant*). I think you are mixing things up. In comments you write that price can be 1 or 3. Are you mixing up price and number?